# Diamond Box Plot and Csm Input Voltages of Op Amps

Tags: operational-amplifier

More details:

With 2 volts common mode input, the allowed red spot is right at the grey area on edge of the white allowed area (bottom of the diamond box).

[image]

It says: "Internal node voltage is exceeding the available supply. What does it mean? Here is the other diagram:

[image]

Is it allowable when it's right on edge of the grey? What is your experience about it?

My original question (and related to it exactly).

https://tools.analog.com/en/diamond/?doc=AN-1401pdf#difL=0.000001&difR=0.000004&difSl=0.000001&gain=50&l=2.2&pr=AD620&r=3&sl=2.2&tab=1&ty=1&vn=0&vp=5&vr=2

[image]

I have 2 concerns.

1.Above is Analog Devices Diamond Plot Tool. The red should be inside the white area. What will happen if it gets slightly into the grey area? Suddenly your circuit will no longer function or is it linear? the farther into grey area, the worse is the performance?

2. Also let's focus on the input voltages or Vcm of op-amps. When you apply input voltages, is it measured with respect to the pin itself like Pin 2 (-IN) or pin 3? (+IN). I'm asking because even though 2 volts were applied to the following. I measured 1.09 volts actual at the input pins 2 and 3.

[image]

The following is the specs sheet of the AD620:

[image]

The internal Common and Differential input impedances are both 10GOhms. So when measuring the voltages at the pin. Are you supposed to assume the 2V source and 20Mohm external are in series with the 10GOhm within the chip forming a complete circuit with the ground? But still it shouldn't produce 1 volts at the output but much lower. So how did the 1.09v come out?

Comment: How did you measure the voltage? With a digital multimeter with 10M input impedance?

Comment: I checked the multimeter manual. Yes!  the multimeter has 10M input impedance. I never thought of it, that it can affect the total resistance and reading. So what meter must I use to measure the real voltage 2 volts appearing in the pin?

Comment: @Jtl: **You need the instrument amp that you are building!** The AD620 has more input resistance at a much lower cost, than what you can buy. Try to find a way to use its own output to make your measurements in conjunction with your DMM. Watch out for leakage currents across surfaces especially ones that have been touched or soldered. Clean with 99% isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: The next step up from the usual 10MOhm multimeter tends to get expensive. Besides you’re moving into dark territory - many things can cause leakage resistances up in the mega ohm range so even if you had a 1TOhm meter, other things would spoil your day. Similarly if you measure microvolts you need to concern yourself with thermal effects, leakage and so on.

Comment: The major question unanswered is, should I add -5 volts -Vs to make the red spot be located inside the diamond box? Right now, it is right at the edge in grey area as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

It is called meter loading. The meter forms a voltage divider with the Thevenin resistance, in this case \$10\text{M}\Omega//10\text{G}\Omega\$. The voltage reading is correct.

Although you can back calculate the unloaded value, measuring will disturb the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzKsjN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: why doesnt it interact with the 10GOhm impedanxe inside the AD620 op amp??

Comment: It does. the 10G is in parallel with the meter, I'll add it to my schematic.

Comment: you mean everytime you measure voltage across any resistor, you have to consider the 10Maohm inside the multimeter? Ive been using my multimeter for over 15 years measuring voltages across resistors and I didnt notice it. maybe there are resistor values that are exceptions?

Comment: Voltage across resistors greater than 1 megaohm definitely read low. Greater than 100k if your after precision. It is easy to set up the simulation in LTspice or CircuitLab. Or to calculate with a voltage divider.

Comment: when the resistor is only 200kOhm. the voltage in the pin measured is 1.978V. so i think if the resistance is very small. Its close to the real voltage..maybe thats why I didnt notice it before.

Comment: That's correct. Whenever a measuring device is attached to a circuit, the circuit is changed. Its fun to push the meter to its limits and still obtain meaningful measurements.

Comment: Isnt there any non contact probe available say one that measures the electric field of the resistor so your measurement would be a non demolition?  bec whenever i touched the probe to measure the pin, the output got distorted. now it made sense why. There must be a non demolition measuring device developer somewhere like in NASA. isnt there? last question tnx

Comment: @RussellH the "input impedance of 10 Gohm" doesn't say anything about the absolute input bias current level and thus doesnt say anything about the voltage. The 10 Gohm sopec is usually just the differential input resistance.

Comment: @tobalt: The common mode input resistance is specified as 10 Gohm as well. See the OP’s post.

Comment: @RussellH Pls tell me. For the 2V dc source in series with the 20MOhm at the pin 2 and 3 of the schematic above in main post. What will happen if the 2V is applied directly at the say pin 2 and ground, you also have 2 volts. Its from an EEG circuit (Brainmaster 2e) I owned and analyzing and improving. Thanks.

Comment: Well... This is becoming circuit design. Your better off to bias through resistance. There is good information at the end of the AD620 data sheet on biasing. You can search SE  for AD620 posts. Cheers.